# Глобальное ajaxError событие перед local error событием

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня есть глобальное ajaxError событие, наподобие:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function myErrorHandler(event, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert("There was a global ajax error!");
});
```

И у меня есть много локальных ajaxEvents, наподобие таких:

```
$(imageUploadForm).ajaxForm({
            url: assetsUplUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {project_id: projectId, type: 'image', widget: widget},
            error: function(responseText, status, xhr, form){
                 alert("There was a local ajax error!");
            }
        });
```

Как я могу вызвать глобальный ajaxError перед тем как сработает один из локальных error событий?

Comment: что за `ajaxError` и `ajaxForm`? глобальное событие вообще вызывается?

Comment: ajaxError устанавливает обработчик Ajax события, когда Ajax-запрос завершен с ошибкой.
ajaxForm - пример локального ajax.
Дело в том что локальный аякс срабатывает раньше чем глобальный а мне надо сделать что бы глобальный срабатывал раньше глобального